# JavaScript simulate right click through code

Tags: javascript, selenium, dojo, mouseevent

I am writing some UI tests using Selenium and i have a JavaScript Tree control, using the Dojo toolkit.

I have implemented a context menu for each node of the tree using the examples that Dojo provide, but I need the Selenium test to "invoke" the right click on the tree node, but I cannot get this to work. The tests simply do not simulate the right-click event through JavaScript, and the context menu does not show up.

Has anyone had any experience in invoking the right click on a context menu using Dojo and Selenium? Or have any ideas as to how to do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try this instead, reason what things didn't quite work is that the context menu is in fact bound to the oncontextmenu event.

```
function contextMenuClick(element){
    var evt = element.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');

    var RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE = 2; // the same for FF and IE

    evt.initMouseEvent('contextmenu', true, true,
         element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false,
         false, false, false, RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE, null);

    if (document.createEventObject){
        // dispatch for IE
       return element.fireEvent('onclick', evt)
     }
    else{
       // dispatch for firefox + others
      return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just for good measure, here is a bit of doco on the parameters:

```
var myEvt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
myEvt.initMouseEvent(
   'click'          // event type
   ,true           // can bubble?
   ,true           // cancelable?
   ,window      // the event's abstract view (should always be window)
   ,1              // mouse click count (or event "detail")
   ,100           // event's screen x coordinate
   ,200           // event's screen y coordinate
   ,100           // event's client x coordinate
   ,200           // event's client y coordinate
   ,false         // whether or not CTRL was pressed during event
   ,false         // whether or not ALT was pressed during event
   ,false         // whether or not SHIFT was pressed during event
   ,false         // whether or not the meta key was pressed during event
   ,1             // indicates which button (if any) caused the mouse event (1 = primary button)
   ,null          // relatedTarget (only applicable for mouseover/mouseout events)
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Great question!

I did some research, and it seems like you can fire a mouse event like [is shown here](http://lifescaler.com/2008/04/simulating-mouse-clicks-in-javascript/), and make it a right-click by setting the `button` or `which` property to 2 ([documented here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button)).

Perhaps this code will work:

```
function rightClick(element){
  var evt = element.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');

  var RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE = 2; // the same for FF and IE

  evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true,
      element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false,
      false, false, false, RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE, null);

  if (document.createEventObject){
    // dispatch for IE
    return element.fireEvent('onclick', evt)
  }
  else{
    // dispatch for firefox + others
    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more correct version if you do not care about where the context menu gets fired up

```
function fireContextMenu(el) {
  var evt = el.ownerDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  evt.initEvent('contextmenu', true, true) // bubbles = true, cancelable = true

  if (document.createEventObject) {
    return el.fireEvent('oncontextmenu', evt)
  }
  else {
    return !el.dispatchEvent(evt)
  }
}
```

If you do, we may have to use the previous one, fix up it's behaviour in IE, and populate the screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY etc appropriately

Comment: Thanks, I dont actually care where it happens, but it might be nice to do so in the future...

Comment: If you are using jQuery, right-clicking an element is even simpler:

    $(your_element).trigger('contextmenu');

Answer (score 2):

I am trying this in firefox and chrome, but dispatching the contextmenu event doesn't make browser to open context menu. Event is triggered because my callback for oncontextmenu is fired, but context menu is still missing. Anybody have an idea, because I used all code samples from above?

Comment: FWIW I have the same problem -- maybe this was disabled in some recent-ish versions for security or something?

Comment: OP implemented his own contextmenu menus, it is not possible to trigger the browser's contextmenu using javascript.