# How to trigger mouse right click programmatically using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I need trigger mouse right click using javascript or jQuery.
Here I tried below code it is not working for me

```
 <div id="testing" style="height:500px;width:1000px;background-color:lime;"></div>
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#testing').contextmenu();
     //or
     $('#testing').trigger({
        type: 'mousedown',
         which: 3
     });
    });
    </script>
```

can you please any provide information on this.

Comment: You can’t open context menus programmatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically Calling Browser Right-Click Menu Options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896362/programmatically-calling-browser-right-click-menu-options)

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testing" style="height:500px;width:1000px;background-color:lime;"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#testing" ).contextmenu(function() {
  alert( "Right clicked" );
});

});
</script>
```