# how can you do right click using selenium?

Tags: selenium, right-click

im trying to preform a right click using selenium, any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: What have you done yourself? Or do you want people to do all the work for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript simulate right click through code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433919/javascript-simulate-right-click-through-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript simulate right click through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433919/javascript-simulate-right-click-through-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [docroots's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2171956/218196) for selenium.

To generally simulate a right click in JavaScript, have a look at [JavaScript simulate right click through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433919/javascript-simulate-right-click-through-code).

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I guess this was before I reached 3000 ;)

Comment: I would delete this answer, but I cannot, since it is the accepted one.

Comment: Appreciate the openness, but it probably isn't worth fussing with now.

Comment: @Marc: You are probably, but I got an upvote for the answer, had a look at it and wanted to set things straight :) My comment was actually not directed at you, but just  a general remark for any reader.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [`OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions` Namespace](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html).

```
// step 1 - select the element you want to right-click
var elementToRightClick = this.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("elementtoclickonhasthisid"));
// step 2 - create and step up an Actions object with your driver
var action = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(this.Driver);
action.ContextClick(elementToRightClick);
// step 3 - execute the action
action.Perform();
```

Answer (score 2):

it appears that for my issue (an element that opens a popup after a right click), using selenium's : mouse_down_right() and then mouse_up_right()
worked as well. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium is offering a method for right click - ContextClick:

```
        public void RightClick(IWebElement target)
        {
            var builder = new Actions(driver);
            builder.ContextClick(target);
            builder.Perform();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried [ActionSequence](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions_exports_ActionSequence.html) and it worked.

ContextClick function is not found, you should use click.

So, it should be as follows:

```
driver.actions().click(element,2).perform();
```

The element is your web element, 2 means right click.