# How to do right click in selenium test

Tags: selenium, richfaces, contextmenu, right-click

I have using recursiveTreeNodesAdaptor in seam. And I want to add child this tree via contextMenu and when user click right node of tree open context menu and click left then open modal panel. I want to do this.

When I try to write selenium test this flow I dont click to rigt and open contextMenu. I try to selenium.contextmenu(xpath) but i'm fail.

So, How can I click to right

---

I tried to simulate right click with user extension. My function is below:

```
Selenium.prototype.doContextMenuClick = function(element){
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');

var RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE = 2; // the same for FF and IE

evt.initMouseEvent('contextmenu', true, true,
     document.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false,
     false, false, false, RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE, null);

if (document.createEventObject){
    // dispatch for IE
return document.fireEvent('onclick', evt);
}
else{
   // dispatch for firefox + others
   return !document.dispatchEvent(evt);
}};
```

I managed to call the function from IDE. But, now, I get the error "this.waitForCondition is not a function". What's wrong? Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using fireEvent on that element.
You should also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433919/javascript-simulate-right-click-through-code) which seems to be about the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The latest selenium has a namespace called OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions Namespace.  check it out [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html).

see my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19123275/2836016)