# Getting src link of XKCD image?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get src(URL) link of main image from xkcd.com website. I am using the following code but it returns something like `session="2f69dd2e-b377-4d1f-9779-16dad1965b81", element="{ca4e825a-88d4-48d3-a564-783f9f976c6b}"`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://xkcd.com')
assert 'xkcd' in browser.title

idlink= browser.find_element_by_id("comic")

#link = idlink.get_attribute("src") ## print link prints null

print idlink
```

using xpath method also returns same as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`browser.find_element_by_id` returns web element, and that is what you print.
In addition, the text you want is in child element of `idlink`. Try

```
idlink = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#comic > img")
print idlink.get_attribute("src")
```

`idlink` is now web element with `img` tag who has parent with `comic` ID.
The URL is in `src` so we want that attribute.

Comment: Also, "comic" is a <div> element which contains the <img>: `<div id="comic">
<img src="//imgs.xkcd.com/comics/tools.png" title="I make tools for managing job-hunting sites for people who make tools for managing job-hunting sites for people who make tools for ..." alt="Tools">
</div>`

Comment: I'm not sure how selenium works, but I suspect that will be significant.

Comment: No idea, but I think the OP is trying to get the URL of the image? Wouldn't they need to get the <img> tag first?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yeah, I see it now

Comment: yeah I need URL of the image actually.

Comment: @featuresky Thanks, I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Building off the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361742/download-image-with-selenium-python)

You need to:

1. Select the img tag (you're currently selecting the div)
2. Get the contents of the source attribute of the img tag

   ```
   img_tag = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='comic']/img")
   print img_tag.get_attribute("src")
   ```

The above should print the URL of the image

More techniques for locating elements using selenium's python bindings are available [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html)

For more on using XPath with Selenium, see [this tutorial](http://hedleyproctor.com/2011/05/tutorial-writing-xpath-selectors-for-selenium-tests/)

Comment: thanks Ur answer works as well. it should be get_attribute("src") up there.

Comment: thanks for the upvote and the edit. :) For me, XPath has been the way to go when working with Selenium... the extra precision has saved my bacon many a time.