# How can I download a image by right clicking using selenium?

Tags: selenium, automation

I have tried to download the image using Context click method and Image is getting selected but unable to download the image ? Please find below code for reference.

```
    WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'41thskyt96l_1_1-e18b7.jpg')]"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.contextClick(we).build().perform();
    action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, "v").build().perform();
```

Please let me know what changes need to be done to download a image ?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: test is passed but I see following message and I'm using firefox browser v52.0.2 (32bit)                                                                    

[Child 4264] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32 00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2143
Jul 19, 2017 10:44:44 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess destroy

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361742/download-image-with-selenium-python

Comment: @NicolasG.Duvivier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361742/download-image-with-selenium-python post has different scenario compare with my post. Thanks !