# Using lxml to scrape a non static site

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am using lxml for the first time and I am running into some issues when I try to scrape data. When I view the part of the code I want to scrape using developer tools, it looks like this. The webapge in question is https://nba.com/hawks/photos

```
<ul id="nbaImageGrid">
    <li class="grid-item">
        <a href="https://...">
            <img src="...">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ...>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I view the page source, the Html looks like this.

```
<ul id="nbaImageGrid" class="loading"></ul>
```

When I tried using lxml to get the a href from each grid-item I get an empty list returned

```
doc.xpath("//li[@class='grid-item']/a/@href")
```

I understand that this webpage is not static and that it is either client-side or server-side generated. Is it still possible to use lxml to scrape this page? If not, can you recommend another python scraping library that I could use to scrape pages like this? 
Additionally, it would be helpful if you could explain if this site is client-side or server-side, and how you can tell.

Thank You!

Comment: I would recommend selenium for this kind of work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361742/download-image-with-selenium-python

Comment: _Is it still possible to use lxml to scrape this page?_ Yes, although I think you're focusing on the part of the process. _If not, can you recommend another python scraping library that I could use to scrape pages like this?_ Explicitly off-topic, see [help/on-topic]. _Additionally, it would be helpful if you could explain if this site is client-side or server-side, and how you can tell._ What do you mean? Are you referring to server-side HTML rendering?

Comment: This isn't really a question about lxml. LXML doesn't fetch HTML from a remote site;  you're obviously using something else (`urllib`, `requests`, etc) for that. Of course it's possible to use `lxml` to scrape data from a dynamic page, but you have to somehow fetch that data and feed it to `lxml`.