# Download an image using the FIND method in Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
captcha_img = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ng-star-inserted')
```

I want to download the image.

Please help.

Comment: Please share your code and URL so that we can help you better. Moreover, do some research before asking questions here. Help yourself with below link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361742/download-image-with-selenium-python

Answer (score 0):

Another option (we get the url address from the `src` attribute, then we download and write the file):

Imports :

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
```

Code :

```
url= driver.find_element_by_class_name('ng-star-inserted').get_attribute("src")
img = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream = True).raw)
img.save('image.jpg')
```

Reference : https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/releasenotes/2.8.0.html#id1