# How can I emulate right-click in the node.js selenium-webdriver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using [selenium-webdriver for nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver).

How can I emulate a right-click with this driver? I can't find this in the official documentation.

Comment: A right click on the client is also known as invoking a **context menu**. Some documentation here: https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/right-click-context-menu-webdriver-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, wmash. You help me found solution.

Answer (found [here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_ActionSequence.html)):

```
driver.actions().click(element1, input.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```