# Perform right click using selenium in node js

Tags: node.js, selenium

I am implementing code where need to be performed right using selenium driver. I have searched, there are plenty of answers but i can't find the relevant answers for right click in NODE JS. How can i perform right click in node js ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I emulate right-click in the node.js selenium-webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912208/how-can-i-emulate-right-click-in-the-node-js-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: thanks for the reply. checking it.

Comment: driver.actions().click(element1, input.Button.RIGHT).perform(); 
i have understand that "element1" is id but i am getting error "input is not defined". what to do now ? please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving answer using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912208/how-can-i-emulate-right-click-in-the-node-js-selenium-webdriver)

```
click( opt_elementOrButton, opt_button )
```

For Complete Info: [document are here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_ActionSequence.html)

**opt_elementOrButton**

Either the element to interact with or the button to click with.

**opt_button**

The button to use. Defaults to input.Button.RIGHT.

Comment: hi 
i have added below code to perform right click but its giving an error.
driver.actions().click(driver.findElement(By.tagName('canvas')),input.Button.right).perform();
ERROR:"Cannot read property 'Button' of undefined" can you please me to get rid of this error?

Comment: thank you so much for help. Error has been removed just got it.

Comment: Please upvot le and accpt as a answer

Comment: I get the same error: ERROR:"Cannot read property 'Button' of undefined" . what did you do to get rid of this error?