# How to right click on a svg element using JavascriptExecutor in selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, svg, selenium-webdriver

I have to right click on a particular portion of my web page.

There are a few svg elements in background layer at the part where i need to right click. These svg elements are in a different layer which is invisible. below is the html code

[HTML Code of the svg elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbmMW.png)

HTML code of visible part (highlighted div element in image with class value containing 'z-Timeline-TimelineTrack') is something like below (you can also see svg elements part in the below code) 
[HTML code of visible part of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE3f8.png)

As you see that there are many 'line' elements.. i need to perform a right click on a specified line.

I am able to locate a particular line element using below xpath

```
@FindBy(xpath ="//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='line'][5]")
public WebElement anyAgendaLine;
```

After searching over internet, i found that i can use JavascriptExecutor to click on any invisible elements. before finding this i tried using Actions to perform context menu click which gave below error

> Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
>   Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (2.5, 0.5):
>   [object SVGLineElement]

My code for context menu click is like:

```
public static void rightClickAndSelectMenuItem(WebElement objWebElement, WebElement menuItem){
        Actions action=new Actions(Setup.driver);
        action.contextClick(objWebElement).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).click(menuItem).build().perform();

}
```

After finding that context menu click doesn't work, i tried just to click on the 'line' element:

```
(JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", objAgendaPage.anyAgendaLine);
```

which gave below error

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: arguments[0].click is not a
>   function

So please help me out here. I am not even able to just perform a click on this invisible 'line' element.
Actually i need to perform a right click.

Comment: Don't use screen shots as code, please put the actual code into the question

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the relevant part of the page? Is it possible to use context click using coordinates instead? Like finding out the location from a container?

Comment: @Liam I just thought it would make the question long and also people can get a quick and clear idea on hierarchy of the elements by using image..

Comment: @Grasshopper sorry for the late reply.. it is working now with the method u mentioned.. I got the location of a SVG element (objAgendaPage.anyAgendaLine) and then used those coordinates to right click on the element (objAgendaPage.timeLineTrack) which visible... below is the code.. actions.moveToElement(objAgendaPage.timeLineTrack, objAgendaPage.anyAgendaLine.getLocation().getX(), objAgendaPage.anyAgendaLine.getLocation().getY()).contextClick().click(objAgendaPage.createAppointmentContextualTable).build().perform();

Comment: @Grasshopper I could not directly perform right click on SVG elements as those are in a different layer which is hidden.. hence i had to get location of SVG element and then perform right click on the element which is visible.. Thanks a lot for helping..

Comment: @Grasshopper however, i could not understand what u meant by finding the location from a container.. i googled about the container but failed to get any info.. please lemme know more about the container stuff..

Answer (score 0):

In order to right click using JavaScript (with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433919/javascript-simulate-right-click-through-code)):

```
js.executeScript("function contextMenuClick(element){
var evt = element.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');

var RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE = 2;

evt.initMouseEvent('contextmenu', true, true,
     element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE, null);

  if (document.createEventObject){
     // dispatch for IE
     return element.fireEvent('onclick', evt)
  }
  else{
     // dispatch for firefox + others
    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
}; contextMenuClick();", objAgendaPage.anyAgendaLine);
```