# Adding JS packages like Selenium to a Chrome Extension

Tags: node.js, selenium, google-chrome, npm, google-chrome-extension

I want to build a Chrome Extension that uses Selenium and other packages for JavaScript.

I can install `selenium-webdriver` with `npm` in my workspace, but can we add packages like these in a Chrome Extension?

Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: What sort of functionality are you looking for?

Comment: @pcalkins I am trying to make an extension to get youtube's "stats for nerds" data automatically every time I watch a video. The html element for "stats for nerds" is not available before right clicking on the video container. Also as far as I researched, JavaScript by itself won't allow right clicking elements. So I thought if I can use something like Selenium to do the right clicking I can access this data.

Comment: Not sure that the extension could run the driver.... if it could you'd still need to have started the browser in dev-mode and received the SessionID so the driver could control it.  You probably want to modify "Selenium IDE" which is already a browser plugin.  (or just use it as is...)

Comment: No things like that are for node only

Comment: [JavaScript simulate right click through code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433919)